# What is Pure Java

Tags: java

I was invited to interview for Pure Java Developer

Please help me to understand what is Pure Java.

Can't find any information about it.

Comment: usually it means J2SE, without need for enterprise edition knowledge or other frameworks (Spring, etc)

Comment: Pure java = java core?

Comment: Ask them what they mean by pure Java. It's not exactly a standard term (unlike Java EE which would be understood by everyone).

Comment: Well actually there is/was a (related) standard term: "100% Pure Java".  It was even trademarked!  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pure Java code is code that ["conforms to Java's ideal of universal portability"](http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/faq/faq0006.html)

It means *code that does not rely on native features*.

An aspect of Java is to be portable across different operating systems (write once, run anywhere). **Writing code that can only be used on specific operating systems contradicts this**.

Simply by googling "Pure Java", you can find resources on it, such as PDFs and other articles.

Comment: one small e.g. may be using `File.separator` instead of \ or /. Because someday your program might run on a platform which might use `;` as the file separator and your application crashes off to moon.

Answer (score 1):

What does "pure Java" mean?

Well, you would need to ask the person who used the phrase<sup>1</sup> to know what *they* meant.  But when a seasoned Java professional hears the phrase, they are *likely* to think it refers to "100% Pure Java".

"100% Pure Java" was a pre-2000 Sun Microsystems initiative to promote the writing of portable Java code.  There is even a ["100% Pure Java Cookbook"](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/100percentpurejavacookbook-4-1-1-150165.pdf) that says how to do it.

What does the "100% pure" mean?

The Cookbook says it like this:

> ### The 100% Pure Java™ Standard
>
> The "100% Pure Java™ Standard" is part of Sun Microsystems initiative
> to promote the development of portable applications, applets<sup>2</sup>, beans,
> class libraries, and servlets written using the Java™ Programming
> language. Compliance to the standard consists of code analysis and
> testing the program on multiple Java Application Environments.

Basically, 100% pure Java is about portability.  It means avoiding things like:

- using native code libraries,
- using external applications,
- making platform and operating system specific assumptions; e.g. that `"\n"` is the line separator or `"/"` is the pathname separator,
- and so on.

This does NOT mean "uses only Java SE or Java EE APIs", although:

- using Java platform vendor's extensions to the standard APIs, or
- using new platform features such as Java 8 streams, etc

both arguably work against Java platform independence.   And Java has *dropped* certain features in more recent releases, which also affects portability and platform independence.  (Try running an applet on a modern JVM ...)

---

<sup>1 - Lots of people are happy to borrow someone else's terminology and give a new meaning to it, then state their new meaning as the real meaning.  In this case, my guess is that the person who invited you to the interview is a recruiter or manager who has minimal technical understanding.  They may be saying "pure Java" because they think it will make the job more attractive to the right kind of prospects.  Or maybe they are confusing "pure Java" with "core Java".  Who knows ...

2- Ahem ... dead technology.</sup>

Answer (score -2):

I would consider 'Pure Java' to be Core Java. The Classes, Interfaces and APIs that are referenced as part of the Javadoc for that particular JDK.

E.g. Oracle JDK 8 - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Comment: it probably was down-voted because it is only an opinion, no reference or similar; maybe because it is not considered accurate; ... in short because someone thought "This answer is not useful"  || BTW if it has one down-vote, it now also has one up-vote (net result +8 reputation points) || BTW2 (@Teddy) making comments compulsory for down-votes was being discussed on [meta] since more than 10 years. afaik. It would not help - we could expect comments like `not useful` or even `asdfasdf`

Comment: Comments with downvotes are not considered compulsory.  In fact, most seasoned StackOverflow users will consciously avoid commenting ... lest they become the target of someone's vitriol.  Votes are anonymous **by design**.

Comment: The Question does not call for opinions.  There are fact-based answers to what Pure Java **originally** meant.  And it is also fact that the way that *some people* use Pure Java is not ... founded on any *agreed* "standard" meaning.   (And this Answer is an example of that, IMO.  Hence the downvote.)

Comment: And if you are saying that it is somehow impolite to downvote an answer that you think is (for example) wrong, sorry but the community doesn't agree with that.  (Go on "meta" and suggest it if you want to gauge people's opinion.  But don't say I didn't warn you.)