# What sorted data structures does java have?

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

What *default* data structures does **pure** java (any version after and including java8) have which store the data in a sorted way, using which you can iterate through the data ?

The only ones I am aware of are :

1. TreeMap
2. TreeSet

There are easy ways to sort other collections e.g. `Collections.sort` etc. But I wanted to find out what *out of the box* data structures does java provide which keep the data sorted outside of the ones I mentioned.

A priority queue (Min/Max heap) also keeps data "sorted" - but you cannot iterate through the data. You have remove the data to iterate through the data in ascending/descending order.

EDIT: Pure java here refers to not using any external libraries e.g. Google Guava, Apache commons etc.

Comment: "any version after and including java8" Are you not interested in Java-7 and below? Why did you even mentioned `Collections.class` if you are only interested with Java-8 and up?

Comment: I think "pure Java" means something different to what you think it means.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31155053

Answer (score 4):

Look at the [interfaces](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) first.

- [NavigableSet](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html), a later sub-interface of [`SortedSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedSet.html) with additional functionality, keeps its elements in sorted order. The [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableSet.html) class is one of two implementations bundled with Java.

  - The [`ConcurrentSkipListSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListSet.html) class is an implementation of `NavigableSet` that adds concurrency features.
- [`NavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NavigableMap.html), a later sub-interface of [`SortedMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SortedMap.html) with additional functionality, promises to keep key-value pairs ordered. One of the two implementations bundled with Java is [`TreeMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/TreeMap.html).

  - [`ConcurrentNavigableMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentNavigableMap.html) extends that interface to make thread safety and atomicity guarantees. Java comes bundled with one implementation, [`ConcurrentSkipListMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html).

All of this information is available to you in the Javadoc. The top of each page has links to related interfaces & classes, grouped in headings *All Superinterfaces:*, *All Known Subinterfaces:*, and *All Known Implementing Classes:*. The Javadoc also indicates the version of Java a class or interface was added; see the *Since:* heading.

I suggest you also explore the rich classes provided in the libraries [*Google Guava*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Guava) and [*Eclipse Collections*](https://www.eclipse.org/collections/).